# Deactivate TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 for website, not server

Tags: ssl, iis-8

I have a client who wants TSL1.0 and 1.1 disabled for their website.

I did that using powershell on the windows 2012R2 server. Perfect. But my MS SQL 2012 server on the machine became inaccessible, so I had to enable the protocols again.

I have been struggling to find ways to only deactivate these for IIS or possibly specific site.

Hope someone can help

Comment: That's impossible. Windows only allows you to set TLS related settings server wide.

Comment: yeah found that much when I broke the site twice :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both IIS and SQL server run Schannel. And its far ahead IIS pipeline. So I'm afraid it's impossible to disable TLS 1.0 AND 1.1 for IIS site separately. Besides, disable TLS1.0 and 1.1 is not kind of best performance operation.

If you still require to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1, then please focus on troubleshooting sql server inaccessible issue via network monitor. But I think you should disable SSL 2.0, 3.0 more than TLS 1.0 1.1.

Comment: Thanks. It is per request from my customer, and reading that it is best practice, that websites don't support these two. So the aim is just to disable it for the visitors to the website really. I guess one solution is an upgrade of server, windows and sql, version?

Comment: Since different environment apply different Schannel configuration by default. It is recommended to montior ssl handshake via network montior then decide which part require to be updated.

Comment: We ended up upgrading the sql server so we could disable/enable what we needed.